# Convert array of string to JAVASCRIPT object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got problem, I've array of string as

```
[
    "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:47.41,Server:Daniel.Europe.A…itical,Area:Europe,Site:,Station:Aberdeen,Stream:", 
    "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:48.16,Server:Daniel.Europe.U…,Area:Europe,Site:United Kingdom,Station:,Stream:"
]
```

I need to convert it to Object

```
[
    {"Time" : "25/10/2019 14:49:47.41", "Server", "Daniel.Europe..", .. },
    {}
]
```

likewise.

JSON.parse won't work on non-serialized string.

Comment: try JSON.stringify(yourArray);

Comment: Either change the process that sends you the data in that format (best option) so it comes in proper JSON format or figure out how to parse it yourself.

Comment: Split each string by `,` and then each of those strings by (the first) `:`.

Comment: An array of string? You basically have one string in an array? Look at @crahsmstr's comment. The essence of the problem is probably in the API/Back-end.

Comment: @crashmstr  I understand it is problem in backend/api, but I can't change it.. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
var data = [
  "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:47.41,Server:Daniel.Europe.A…itical,Area:Europe,Site:,Station:Aberdeen,Stream:",
  "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:48.16,Server:Daniel.Europe.U…,Area:Europe,Site:United Kingdom,Station:,Stream:"
]

var result = data.map(v => 
  Object.fromEntries(v.split(',').map(v => v.split(/:(.*)/)))
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: But... is less browser compatible than reduce: https://caniuse.com/#search=fromEntries not IE/Edge support

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
input.map(v => v.split(',').map(v => {
    const [key, ...value] = v.split(':');
    const obj = {};
    obj[key] = value.join(':');
    return obj;
}))
```

Comment: careful. `split()` will discard your time string after the first colon. See @User863 answer.

Comment: @mankowitz That doesn't appear to be the case in my testing. That would only happen if you supplied `2` as the 2nd argument to `.split`

Comment: @DanielSamuels Ohhh. I had used the 2nd argument in my code. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using map and reduce:

```js
const arr = [
    "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:47.41,Server:Daniel.Europe.A…itical,Area:Europe,Site:,Station:Aberdeen,Stream:", 
    "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:48.16,Server:Daniel.Europe.U…,Area:Europe,Site:United Kingdom,Station:,Stream:"
]

const newArr = arr.map(item => {
return item.split(",").reduce((acc, curr) => {  
  const label = curr.split(":")[0];
  const value = curr.substring(label.length+1)
  acc[curr.split(":")[0]] = value
  return acc;
},{})
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your strings by commas and colons. Only problem is that your time string has a bunch of colons in it. Here is a start.

```js
var a = [
    "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:47.41,Server:Daniel.Europe.A…itical,Area:Europe,Site:,Station:Aberdeen,Stream:", 
    "Time:25/10/2019 14:49:48.16,Server:Daniel.Europe.U…,Area:Europe,Site:United Kingdom,Station:,Stream:"
];

b = a.map(function(line) {
  var obj = {};
  line.split(",").forEach(function(item) {
    kv = item.split(/:(.+)/,2);
    obj[kv[0]]=kv[1];
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(b);
```